# Appending new value to dictionary key gives AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'append'

Tags: python-3.x, integer, append, attributeerror

I'm trying to map list into dictionary with enumerate() function but when I tried to append new value to key, value pair with append it gives AttributeError.
As per my understanding I think integers does not accept append function but I'm not appending to an integer then why I'm getting such error. Here is my code:

```
movies = ['star wars', 'avenger', 'iron man', 'spider man', 'star wars', 'spider man', 'iron man', 'star wars', 'star wars']
schedule = {}

for day, movie in enumerate(movies):
  if movie not in schedule:
    schedule[movie] = day
  else:
    schedule[movie].append(day)
print(schedule)
```

Please let me know if anyone know how to deal with it.

Comment: Hi Krushna, in order to make your code reproducible for users, you should add an example of `movies`. I guess it is a list of strings, but this is just a guess... In best case, a user should be able to copy paste your example to reproduce your error.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `append` method is defined for lists, but you're never creating a list in your code. The value of `schedule[movie]` gets set to `day`, which is an integer. You can't append to that value later!

I suspect you want `schedule` to always have values that are lists. In that case, you need to do the initial assignment with a list that contains the first day, rather than the day value directly:

```
if movie not in schedule:
    schedule[movie] = [day]      # add brackets to make a list
else:
    schedule[movie].append(day)  # now this will work
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes you are totally correct, I just found out that after few tries.

Answer (score 0):

As @Blckknght already explained, you are trying to append to an integer which does not have an append method.
For the task you are trying to do, the standard library provides the default dictionary in the `collections` module.

```
from collections import defaultdict
schedule = defaultdict(list)

for day, movie in enumerate(movies):
  schedule[movie].append(day)
print(schedule)
```

If you want to learn more about the default dictionary, I recommend to read https://realpython.com/python-defaultdict/.